# wanderlust: using "To" in wl-template-alist only for new messages, not replies

Tags: email, wanderlust

In `wanderlust`, I have several folders with which I use `wl-template-alist` to set up default values for some of the headers when I am writing messages. In one of these folders (not all of them), I want to use the `"To"` value from `wl-template-alist` only for new messages. If I am replying, I want `To` to be automatically set to the sender's address.

For example ...

```
(setq wl-template-alist
  '(("certainfolder"
    ("To" . "default-recipient-address@domain.com")
    ;;; other stuff
    )))
```

In this case, I want `To` to be set to `default-recipient-address@domain.com` when I'm in "certainfolder" and writing a new message, but I want this to be ignored and the sender's address (or their `Reply-To`) to be used in `To` when I'm generating a reply to any messages in that folder.

How can I do this via `wl-template-alist` for this one, single folder?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you could accomplish what you want (more or less) via a combination `wl-draft-config-alist` and `wl-template-alist`. But in Wanderlust you have two choices: either choose a template for a list, or automatically apply changes to an email, based on matching various. It kind of sounds like you want to do both at once, which isn't possible as far as I know.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Hmm ... but is there a way I can associate a function with "To" in `wl-template-alist` instead of a hard-coded string? If so, perhaps I could have the function check whether I'm creating a new message or a reply and then generate the "To" string accordingly. Could that be possible?

Comment: It appears that you can use arbitrary code in the cdr, so there might be something you can do:

`
(setq wl-template-alist
      `(("my-template"
         ("To" . (if (and (stringp wl-draft-parent-folder)
                          (string-match ".*gmail.com.*" wl-draft-parent-folder))
                     "me@gmail.com"
                   "me@other.com"))
`